# svg background scaling differently from padding

Tags: css, svg

I'm setting an svg as a background image for a div (set as a table-cell, but now it's not the point). It stretches to fit the space, and that's what I wanted, and I set some padding (IN % units) to keep the text inside the image. Now the problem is that scaling the viewport or just changing the height of the div padding and image height change differently so the text positioning is scrambled. Here is the css code:

```
#contenuto {
  border: 0px solid;
  width: 79%;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  padding-top: 1.5%;
  padding-bottom: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 7%;
  background: url(./pic/template.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position:center center;
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

the svg file is properly set I guess:

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 640" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

What can I do to fix?

Comment: Try this: `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"`

Comment: That would preserve it's aspect ratio, resulting in it not fitting in one direction

Comment: Can you post the complete code? Make a snippet out of it if possible. Also, are you aware that a top and bottom padding in % refer to the width of the box, not the height.